# Hadoop. How to get Job from Mapper

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm new in Hadoop. This time I'm realising word counter for inputted keyword. Also I read that using `Job` class better than `JobConf`. So I have this code for main class:

```
...
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("keyword", args[0]);
Job job = new Job(conf);
...
```

So how I can get my keyword in `Mapper` back? As I understand I need to get my `Job` object and from `Job` get `Configuration` object using `getConfiguration()` method and than call `get("keyword")` method.

But how I need to get `Job` from `Mapper` class?

Thank's for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When map is called on your Mapper implementation it is passed a Context object that exposes a getConfiguration method. This will give you what you want.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much! And `Job` is really better than `JobConf` or I something wrong read?

Comment: JobConf was deprecated in favor of the newer Configuration type, so you should use that instead of JobConf if you can.

Comment: Job is part of the new API, JobConf was deprecated

Answer (score 1):

The code you have used to set the parameter in conf looks alright.

From the mapper function, this is what you need to do:

```
Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
String keyword = conf.get("keyword");
```